# Dit-on plutôt « de » ou « de chez » dans « Dans la file de voitures au service à l’auto de [chez] Tim Hortons »?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Dit-on plutôt:

Je dois mon retard au fait que j’étais pris  dans la longue file de voitures au service à l’auto de Tim Hortons.

Je dois mon retard au fait que j’étais pris dans la longue file de voitures au service à l’auto de chez Tim Hortons.

Comment: *Je suis en retard parce que j'étais coincé dans la file d'attente au drive de Tim Hortons.*

Comment: @jlliagre La phrase m'a l'air d'être du québecois ("auto" + Tim Hortons qui est Canadien), je pense pas qu'on dise "au drive" là-bas :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Je ne sais pas si ça se dit ou pas, on doit peut-être préférer *au drive-thru* si on veut garder *drive*. Ce qui est sûr, c'est qu'on ne connait pas *service à l'auto* en France. J'ai d'abord cru que c'était à une station-service que ça bouchonnait avant de trouver ce qu'était *Tim Hortons*. Mon commentaire n'est pas une réponse, juste un exemple de ce que j'aurais dit moi-même dans ce contexte.

Comment: le drive, c'est un service de vente à emporter en voiture (France) et sur Termium, il n'y a pas drive-through take out etc. Termium a: drive-through convenience store, qu'ils traduisent par: **service de dépanneur au volant**. Sur cette base alors: service-café au volant puisque Tim Hortons est un vendeur de café, style Starbucks. Traduction: une longue file d'attente pour **le service au volant** de Tim Hortons

Comment: Tonton Café Restaurant à Montréal: [...] « On parle d'adapter mon menu pour en faire une version restauration rapide, avec **service au volant**. Peut-être même cette année, j’aimerais bien rouvrir un autre Tonton Café dans Limoilou, et aussi à Montréal. » https://monsaintsauveur.com/2022/tonton-cafe-restaurant-ambiance-intimite-retrouvees/

Comment: @jlliagre Eh bien, je savais pas qu'on employait _au drive_ ! L'emprunt qui m'est familier c'est _drive thru_ mais je le dis rarement, peut-être dans une interrogation suivant la mention du lieu « est-ce qu'ils ont un drive-thru eux-autres », peut-être...

Comment: Restaurants - service au volant 
FROMAGERIE VICTORIA - lundi au vendredi de 6 h à 19 h | samedi et dimanche de 8 h à 19 h
TIM HORTONS - Tous les jours de 5 h à 21 h
MCDONALD'S - Dimanche au jeudi de 6 h à 22 h | vendredi et samedi de 6 h à minuit
RÔTISSERIE FUSÉE – Samedi au mercredi de 11 h à 21 h | jeudi et vendredi de 11 h à 22 h https://plessisville.quebec/actualites/informations-diverses---commerces-et-obnl-de-la-ville/

Comment: Terme
service au volant   n. m.
recommandé officiellement par la Commission d'enrichissement de la langue française (France) https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26535661 A la même page que service à l'auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On met ***chez*** si ça fait partie du nom du lieu ou s'il y a risque de confusion avec une personne (*Je suis sur le parking de **Chez** Léon*, *Le Chasseur de **chez** Maxim's*).

Tim Hortons étant un nom d'établissement bien connu au Québec, le *chez* n'est pas nécessaire.

> [...] au service à l’auto de Tim Hortons.

Answer (score 0):

> Je suis en retard parce qu'il y avait b(i)en/beaucoup du monde au
> [service à l'auto](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8361613) au/(de)[chez](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1593)/de/du *Tim (Hortons)*.
> Tout le monde voulais *dérouler le rebord*, la file faisait la moitié de Taschereau !

J'accepte différentes prépositions par flexibilité (et pour justifier un café), selon que je désire marquer davantage l'endroit ou la complémentation, et selon ma perception du nom de l'entreprise ou quand j'omets « Hortons » (*aller au Tim* : « j'men vais au Tim »). D'autre part « auto au » et « au... au » se disent mal ici. Je préfère le générique sous-jacent (*café*, l'endroit, pour les beignes je préfère *Dunkin' Donuts*) avec *du* et *Tim* seul (*du Tim*) ; ou *chez Tim Hortons* ; je trouve *de chez* répétitif dans ce cas.